# What is the origin of "number" as in song or dance?

Tags: etymology, history

What is the origin of ***number*** as another word for a song or dance?

For example:

> And then, when Astro came out to perform his sing-off against Ms. Francis for the right to stay in the competition, he gave the judges and the studio audience a bucketful of attitude. He said he didn’t think he should have to perform. Then he asked the audience if it wanted to hear him **do a number** (which, of course, it did). And he rolled out a less-than-his-best rap over “Never Can Say Goodbye.”.

Comment: The number is a musical number. From the NOAD (def. 3)—"a song, dance, piece of music, etc., esp. one of several in a performance". *Do a number* is not the idiom here, but simply *number*.

Comment: Carlo_R You should edit your question by adding those details. And @zpletan is correct. If that is what you meant, which I didn't realize, then this isn't about an idiom at all. There is a different usage for "do a number" which means "to deceive". Now ***that*** is an idiom.

Comment: @FeralOink  And I just made a fantastic answer explaining *that* idiom!  Grr....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Do a number* on stage means *perform a number*, where *[number](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/number)* means:

> **14.** a single or distinct performance within a show, as a song or dance: *The comic routine followed the dance number.*

The etymology of this usage of *number* is ([Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=number&searchmode=none)):

> The meaning "musical selection" is from vaudeville theater programs, where acts were marked by a number.

Imagine a program for an evening's entertainment:

> I: An Evening in Venice
>
> II: Gondola Suites
>
> III: Maria
>
> Etc, etc, etc

If you were on *Gondola Suites*, you would refer to *Maria* as "the next number".

---

As the question was initially unclear as to which idiom was meant, my original answer had to do with the idiom *do a number **on***.  I kept the original, in case it's interesting:

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+a+number+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0) shows that the expression *[to do a number on something](http://www.languagehat.com/archives/003235.php)* (meaning *to act with destructive force or impact; to criticize or humiliate* - OED) probably began to arise around 1970 (I turned smoothing to zero on purpose):

[image]

[Here's an example](https://books.google.com/books?id=qV0fAQAAMAAJ&q=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&dq=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KLxwT9OGJsTo0QHJ94TxBg&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBQ):

> Our politicians, as you know, can really do a number on each other.

I checked the [context](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1976&lr=lang_en) of the pre-1976 occurrences, and [the 1900s hump](https://books.google.com/books?id=gtYnAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2tNwT6j7H8Pe0QG60JDQBg&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&f=false) is a fluke.  I also don't know about that 1950 bit, but by the contexts cited, I'd say it arose in the late 1960s.

As to the evolution of the phrase, dictionaries and references are chary of suggestions, either [not including the phrase](http://ask.reference.com/web?s=t&q=do%20a%20number&l=dir&qsrc=2891&o=10616), [not including any etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do_a_number_on), or saying *[origin unknown](http://www.idiomsinthenews.com/content/do-a-number-on)*.  [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080930211601AAJFud5) sports some brazen and insupportable speculation, as is its wont; there isn't much to see.

Here's my speculation: *do a number* means *perform a song or dance*.  [The Synonym Finder](https://books.google.com/books?id=kjWZMyVa6jgC&pg=PA877&dq=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KLxwT9OGJsTo0QHJ94TxBg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22do%20a%20number%20on%22&f=false) (1978, Google books) lists *do a number on* as a synonym for *mock*:

[image]

*[On](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on?s=t)* would be in the sense of:

> **12.** with respect or regard to (used to indicate the object of an action directed against or toward): *Let's play a joke on him. Write a critical essay on Shakespeare.*

So *doing a number on someone* means *performing an act based on someone* - *mocking someone*.

From *mocking someone* the meaning morphed to *humiliating someone*, and then, more generally, to *hurting someone* and even *destroying something* (as in *you're really doing a number on that sandwich!*).

Comment: I thought that too, but this is what the question was truly about http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/what-is-the-origin-of-do-a-number#comment119012_62371

Comment: OK, now it's more to the point, but I'm not discarding my research on the other idiom - just pushing it to the end ;)

Comment: It's a good and interesting answer ... even if it's not what the OP wanted to know!

Comment: Musically I would think it could extend further back to numbered classical pieces such as [Bach's Cantata no. 211](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweigt_stille,_plaudert_nicht,_BWV_211), also known as BWV 211.  [Other composers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BWV#Catalogues_of_other_composers) used similar cataloging.

Comment: @Jay Agreed! Haven't seen *chary* before either. It is a perfectly chosen word.

Answer (score 2):

> And then, when Astro came out to perform his sing-off against Ms. Francis for the right to stay in the competition, he gave the judges and the studio audience a bucketful of attitude. He said he didn’t think he should have to perform. Then he asked the audience if it wanted to hear him **do a number** (which, of course, it did). And he rolled out a less-than-his-best rap over “Never Can Say Goodbye.”

It's not a phrase. You just parse it wrong. Here, a [*number*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/number) is:

> 8) (countable) A performance; especially, a single song or song and dance routine within a larger show.
>
> > For his second number, he sang "The Moon Shines Bright".

Therefore the original text, "do a number" simply means "do a performance" = "perform".

Comment: Yes, but what is the origin of the usage?

Comment: @RiMMER: I agree with you: 'do a number', also in my language, simply means 'do a performance'. But, as zpletan said, what is the origin of the usage? In my language ('fai un numero')  there is not an origin, thus I think it derive from the  translaction of english "do a number".